# Newest question feed changes while viewing

Tags: feature-request

I have noticed while looking through newest questions feed the pages change while I am looking through them resulting in me never seeing some questions and  seeing some questions multiple times. Also if I change the number of results per page it skips a few pages of results. So I suggest instead of having a page system like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest

which is a webpage that changes content every time a post is added

use a more static approach like:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?top=29492509&sort=newest

where top represents the id for the question that appears on the top of the page.

This would allow users to accurately browse the questions in the newest questions feed.

Comment: That's unintuitive and doesn't take deleted or merged questions into account. And re "never seeing some questions", there's multiple thousand new  questions on SO each day, you wouldn't have the time to look at them all unless you do nothing else and take about 5 seconds per question.

Comment: @l4mpi What about seeing the same questions multiple times, because this website is so busy there are times when going to the 'next page' renders results that are almost exactly the same as the page that was just viewed. What I am suggesting is to look through the feed for the 'top' question and displaying the next n questions where n is the number of questions per page. Then selecting next page would change the value of 'top' to the question n+1 after the original 'top' value. If the question is deleted then just redirect to the next question that is after it using the time stamp.

Comment: How about simply using a view of the site that is actually usable? E.g. filter by tags and _then_ sort by newest.

Comment: What if you want to see all the questions.

Comment: For what reason? As I said above, if you want to see all the questions, you'll have to deal with the fact that there are so many of them that you at most have a few seconds to look at each if you want to keep up with all of them. And then you'll also have to deal with the site being optimized for using it in ways that actually make sense - as in, _not_ looking at all questions unfiltered and in real time.

Comment: "Also if I change the number of results per page it skips a few pages of results." - You need to do this on the newest page of results. It's changing the number of results when you're on page 5 or something that would do this.

Comment: You could see if there's a StackApp that lets you search/view questions by date: http://stackapps.com/ I did search for "Is there an app that" and got several hits but none for sorting by date. So you could even post that as a question.

Comment: Rather than going to page 2, why not refresh page 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a way to do something close to this. The search bar allows us to [search by create date](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). While the help page only talks about the date, month, and year, it is actually possible to include the time in the search, like this:

```
created:2015-04-28T14:07:02+00:00
```

You can also do ranges and relative dates (see the first link). To see all questions created on or before a specific date time, create a range with no beginning date. Example:

[..created:2015-04-28T14:07:02+00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=created%3A..2015-04-28T14%3A07%3A02%2B00%3A00)

If you do a search like this you don't have to worry about new questions showing up after you've started looking.

---

ETA: 5/15/2015

It looks like they just added a new feature that does something similar to what you want: [Big arrow navigation confusing for home page lists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294440/big-arrow-navigation-confusing-for-home-page-lists)

Now if you click on a question from the home page you can use the arrows to the left/right of the page to cycle through the questions.