# Big arrow navigation confusing for home page lists

Tags: discussion, design, navigation-arrows

I just saw the new arrows at the right and left of posts. It doesn't make sense for me to thumb through home page lists as they are unordered and "random". They also disappear when I click the question title?

The UI makes more sense when I'm actually searching for something.

I'm talking about these new guys on the left and right. (Bottom of the image)

[image]

Comment: There's been at least one meta feature-request from someone who wanted to [see all the questions submitted in order](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289569/newest-question-feed-changes-while-viewing). This feature seems to be for people who want to be able to do that.

Comment: Looks like this is going through A/B testing (or I just can't see them).

Comment: @KevinBrown Clear your cache.

Comment: @KevinBrown I can see them... but I have to zoom out...

Comment: @Braiam Get a bigger monitor…