# New next/previous question button introduced. How does it work?

Tags: support, navigation-arrows

I see new previews and next button on some questions. like:

[image]
[image]

It showed on some questions but didn't show on some.

Like:

[image]

So actually how does it work? Why didn't it show on some pages?

Comment: **[caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)** might be the reason.

Comment: I cleaning cache. but didn't effect. And i open some page previous of that on which it shows.

Comment: This is server-side caching, not your browser's cache.

Comment: Was that really a real question? (the screenshot, I mean)

Comment: @Dave: I weep to inform you that it's [really real](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271581/how-to-make-my-own-operating-system). The only remaining hope is that it's a silly timewasting joke.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294445/provide-a-way-to-disable-the-new-next-previous-question-buttons , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294440/2675154

Comment: [They are introduced for testing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294445/provide-a-way-to-disable-the-new-next-previous-question-buttons#comment194461_294445)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arrows are only showing up if you clicked on a question from a list like the "newest question" list from the home page or a list for a tag. The arrows just take you to the next or previous question in the list.